# How to resume paused upgrade to 18.10?

Tags: kde, do-release-upgrade, 18.10

I was attempting an upgrade to the new 18.10 version of Kubuntu through Konsole.

In the process, I was asked if I want the packages which are unneeded to be deleted. There were three options: Y, N, and Details. I choose `Details`, but didn't know how to get back after the list came to the foreground, so I hit the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and that terminated the whole process.

While I was trying to get back to the process through the `fg` command, Konsole closed unexpectedly and now I can't even reboot my system because of a problem with `ksmserver-logout-greeter`...

Any idea how to get back into the upgrading process without any bad consequences?

Comment: Open TTY mode, login and try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. I think this must solve the issue. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Done, but I'm not sure what supposes to happen and don't know how to see if the process of upgrading is finished or not. The inability to perform a reboot or shutdown is still a fact.

Comment: Are you able to do that sucessfully? Have you tried rebooting or shutting down from command line?

Comment: Yes, I am able. I did a reboot and even tried to repair broken packages through recovery mode, but there's a problem. When I get into Grub I see this: 
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-10-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-10-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-38-generic (recovery mode)

Comment: I tried the both "recovery mode" versions, but when I attempt the "Repair broken packages" option I've received this message:

/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory 
^[[C^[[D 
Reading cache 

Can not upgrade 

Your python install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python' symlink.